# Map custom OpenID Connect claim to contact attribute

Tags: openid-connect, dynamics-crm-portals

I am using the OpenID Connect provider (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/configure-openid-settings) for authentication in Dynamics 365 portals.

The Sid is automatically set as the userId. Is it possible to map other custom claims to attributes on the created contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for OpenID Connect Provider, but you can do claims mapping for [Azure AD B2C provider settings for portals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c#claims-mapping), so the same process might work given similar site settings are being used.

> Name:
>   Authentication/OpenIdConnect/[Federation-Name]/RegistrationClaimsMapping
>
> Description: List of logical name/claim pairs to be used to map claim
>   values to attributes in the contact record created during
>   registration.
>
> Format: attribute1=claim1,attribute2=claim2,attribute3=claim3
>
> For example:
>   firstname=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname,lastname=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname,jobtitle=jobTitle